# Mod dashboard (account info) empty when viewed on iPhone

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, mobile-safari

The Mod dashboard with extended account information doesn't work when viewed in Safari on an iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 10.3.2). It just shows an empty page, e.g. for [this suspicious user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/account-info/121968):

[image]

It seems the content is just not rendered; if I view the source of the page, the `#content` element is empty:

```
    <div id="content">





    </div>
```

Switching to Chrome doesn't help (probably because it's the same browser engine underneath). I *can't* reproduce the issue on an iPad Mini (iOS 9), so it's likely a phone-only issue.

Comment: I don't think there is any support for this. The correct us case is to select the Desktop version :-)

Comment: This *is* the Desktop version of the site.

Comment: FWIW, no repro on Safari on iPad Mini 4 running IOS 10.3.2.

Comment: No repro here. Is it just that user?

Comment: @Cai I have the same problem with your and Mithrandir's account.

Comment: What about other browser on your mobile device? If specific to Safari don't think it's big deal, there are many better browsers out there.

Comment: On iOS, all browser engines are the same as Safari's. Chrome has the same problem.

Comment: This is how I always do it@Glorfindel. It works for me on all my android devices, and my iPad. I don't have an iPhone to test it with.

Comment: @RoryAlsop thanks. It seems the iPhone is the odd one out, then. I have another iPhone I can test with, but it's at home and drained.

Comment: This only happens if you haven't explicitly switched to the full site version of the site before viewing the page (e.g. you browse with the mobile version and then ended up on that page). At least for me. If I click full site and *then* visit the page, it displays fine.

Comment: @animuson yes, that 'fixes' it. Still, it's a mystery why it does work on an iPad (and Android according to RoryAlsop) and other pages (/review), and it's not really an acceptable workaround because I'd like to keep the mobile version for the other pages. I'd like to keep the question open (so not [status-bydesign] or something) because I think it still needs proper fixing (even if that means within the next 6-8 years).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> within the next 6-8 years

It only took 5... Now that the mobile web views have been properly retired, this should be fixed. See [Catija's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376956/323179).