# Flagging comments on mobile is impossible unless you previously switched to desktop view prior to mobile site removal

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags, mobile-web

Do not press "mobile" at the bottom of the page or otherwise try to reproduce this bug! While this flag bug was fixed, there are other subtle bugs with the same root cause. It's very hard to get back to a workable state!

---

On the sites where I do see a flag icon on comments, I can remove it by tapping "mobile" at the bottom of the page (even on desktop). On many more sites I never used the desktop view and so on my phone the option to flag is just not there at all. It really is gone as not even tapping in the blank space works.

Here is a demonstration (I flagged the last comment on desktop):

[image: missing flag icons on all comments, last one is missing upvote icon too]

This is kind of an important bug, since I don't want to see people getting harassed.

Workarounds:

- Request desktop site via your browser. This works on mobile [Safari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336883/323179) and mobile Firefox, but not mobile [Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319370/323179).
- For mobile Chrome (also should work for other browsers), I added the bookmarklet `javascript:StackExchange.switchMobile("off");window.alert('fixed!');` which works. It was convoluted to set up:

  - You can bookmark this page and then edit the bookmark URL to be the code. Visit the site that you're having problems on and it will alert you that it was fixed and reload the page.
  - If your bookmarks are being synced with desktop Chrome, then you can create the bookmarklet there. You'll still have to run it on every site you have issues on.
- Delete cookies, but only if you're using desktop. (It will have the opposite effect on mobile!) You get the best results if you can delete only the "theme" cookie.

  - If only editing cookies was possible on mobile....
- Otherwise, for those truly awful comments in the meantime, you could
  use a custom mod flag on the post, preferably linking here for an
  explanation.

---

This isn't the only bug caused by this; I'm now noticing this bug is caused by the same thing: [After clicking the "edit tags" link, a pop-up appears: "An error occurred when fetching the tag editor"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376282/323179)

Comment: I'm a mod everywhere and I can't flag comments anywhere, even on sites where I have thousands in rep. :/ Also, I use mobile Safari, so I think the common element is the iPhone, thus removal of the [tag:mobile-chrome] tag. We were just talking about it in the Tavern and someone in there on Android can flag just fine.

Comment: Hmmm... but you say that it isn't an issue on Mobile Safari. Now I'm even more perplexed. Can you flag comments in Safari on Writing?

Comment: @Catija Maybe it's the type of iPhone as I tested mobile Safari on my other phone and it worked. Also, I have no problem flagging as a mod no matter the device/browser.

Comment: I'm on an 11 Pro running iOS 14.6. I'll see if updating the phone addresses this.

Comment: @Laurel What happens if you click [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqXN1.png) option in the bottom page?

Comment: For me it's different. I'm using Microsoft Edge on a recent iPhone. I can't flag comments on Ask Ubuntu on mobile at all despite having over 2k rep there. If I set my browser to request the desktop site there, I can flag questions fine. Interestingly, on Meta SE (where I have 243 rep), I can also only flag comments if I specifically request the desktop site. Tl;dr: I can flag normally if I request the desktop site. With the mobile site, I can't flag comments at all, even on AU where I have over 2k rep. But if I request the desktop site, I can flag normally everywhere

Comment: @cocomac You're right. I no longer see the mobile layout on questions (or any page) anymore but it looks like the cookie still exists and is causing trouble as I knew it would. (This isn't the first such bug I've seen along these lines.)

Comment: I've "requested desktop" in mobile Safari and I still don't have flags. :( Hopefully we can figure out what's up.

Comment: @Catija you might also have to do it the other way (in addition to the switch?), which is the button which says "request desktop". In any case I was able to freely switch between messed up and desktop modes in safari.

Comment: Repro'd on chrome on android.

Comment: Looks like we've identified the problem and will be poking it into submission. For stuff we don't identify, it looks like we'll be removing all of the mobile-specific conditions when we remove the buttons and even people with active cookies shouldn't have issues as the cookie won't be used. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the retiring of all of the mobile customizations last week, these bugs should all be gone. I've poked around with my phone and the ones that I've seen do seem to have been fixed. This includes:

- Flagging comments (Fixed 17 Feb 2022)
- Inline tag editing
- Pagination on user profile pages
- Linked and Related questions missing from bottom of page
- User dashboard (mod only)
- Account Info pane (mod only)

There shouldn't be any outstanding differences between full site and mobile experiences but if you do find any, please create a new bug report for them.

Please note, there are a few outstanding issues due to some elements of the sites not being converted to Stacks (responsive) designs. This includes some modals (e.g. the on post suggested edit review modal and mod message type selection modal) and other tools like the avatar image upload. We have documented many of these issues to update in the future and will be working on them soon.

Answer (score 12):

Repro'd on Chrome 98 for Windows with mobile mode on.

This is the source code when **mobile mode is off**.

[image]There are 3 `<div>` tags inside the `comment-actions` grid:

- `comment-score`
- `comment-voting`
- `comment-flagging`

This is the source code when **mobile mode is on**.

[image]There are only 2 `<div>` tags inside the `comment-actions` grid with `comment-flagging` missing.

Answer (score 5):

I think this has something to do with responsive-'[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZZLL.png)'.

### Before clicking 'mobile':

[image: flag buttons are available for comments]

### After clicking 'mobile':

[image: flag buttons for comments have disappeared]

Also, note that related and linked questions tabs disappear.